# MVC3 Some of my fields validate while some do not

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation

Im sitting here scratching my head with a validation problem in ASP MVC3.

Somehow I'm able to validate the field Quantity, but the field OrderNumber does not validate. I can leave it empty and it still accepts it. I've tried to add other restrictions to it as well (such as max and min length) but same result - it accepts anything.

I also try changing 'TextBoxFor' to 'EditorFor' - but it's the same result.

Quantity on the other hand works as I want it. It requires you to enter an integer and it cannot be blank.

Hopefully some of you will be able to see what I'm doing wrong here :)

Here is my model:

```
public class Order
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Insert Ordernumber (6-digits)")]
    public string OrderNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Partnumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public long Quantity { get; set; }

    public Order()
    {
    }
}
```

And here is my view :

```
model POWeb.Models.AddModel
```

@using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{

```
//Create table
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Select Partnumber to produce</td>
        <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedPartNumber, Model.PartNumbers)</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Enter PO number</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.OrderNumber)@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OrderNumber)</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Quantity</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Quantity)@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Quantity)</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <button type="submit" name="SubmitButton">Add</button>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the view of type `POWeb.Models.AddModel`, but you try to validate `Order` type. I'm pretty sure validation attributes on those types are not the same, so you get problems

Comment: You are absolutely right.

I changed to using 'Order' as model and now it works (Removed AddModel as it is not needed). That was a rookie mistake. Nice to get some extra pair of eyes some times. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Anders,

My 'guess' is that your ViewModel model `POWeb.Models.AddModel` isn't mirroring the `[Required]` attribute on `OrderNumber`. Can you add the definition of `AddModel` to your question for verification on that please as it's more than likely that the Order class differs.

Comment: glad to have been of assistance :)

Comment: Yes thanks for your help as well. Got me thinking about the horrible things I was actually doing :) hehe..